# Separate initialization and display of plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

What is a proper way to separate the initialization and the display of plots in Matlab? (I mean *plots* in a wide sense here; could be `plot`, `plot3`, `scatter` etc.) To give a concrete example, I have a pretty complex 3D visualization that uses `sphere` and `mesh` to draw a static sphere mesh and then `scatter3` to plot a moving trajectory on the sphere. To be able to do this in real time I have implemented some simple optimizations, such as only updating the `scatter3` object each frame. But the code is a bit messy, making it hard to add additional features that I want, so I would like improve code separation.

[image: Plot of moving trajectory on sphere.]

I also feel like it might sometimes be useful to return some kind of plot object from a function without displaying it, for example to combine it with other plots in a nice modular way.

An example of what I have in mind would be something like this:

```matlab
function frames = spherePlot(solution, options)
    % Initialize sphere mesh and scatter objects, configure properties.
    ...
    
    % Configure axes, maybe figure as well.
    ...
    
    % Draw sphere.
    ...
    
    if options.display
        % Display figure.
    end
    
    for step = 1:solution.length
        % Update scatter object, redraw, save frame.
        % The frames are saved for use with 'movie' or 'VideoWriter'.
    end
end
```

Each step might also be separated out as a function.

So, what is a neat and proper way to do stuff like this? All documentation seems to assume that one wants to display everything right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```matlab
% some sample data
N = 100;
phi = linspace(-pi, pi, N);
theta = linspace(-pi, pi, N);
f = @(phi, theta) [sin(phi).*cos(theta); sin(phi).*sin(theta); cos(phi)];
data = f(phi, theta);

% init plot
figure(1); clf
plot3(data(1,:), data(2,:), data(3,:)); % plot path, not updated
hold on 
p = plot3([0 data(1,1)], [0 data(2,1)], [0 data(3,1)]); % save handle to graphics objects to update
s = scatter3(data(1,1), data(2,1), data(3,1), 'filled');
axis equal
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
t = title('first frame'); % also store handle for title or labels to update during animation

% now animate the figure
for k = 1:N
    p.XData = [0 data(1,k)]; % update line data
    p.YData = [0 data(2,k)];
    p.ZData = [0 data(3,k)];

    s.XData = data(1,k); % update scatter data
    s.YData = data(2,k);
    s.ZData = data(3,k);

    t.String = sprintf('frame %i', k); % update title
    
    drawnow % update figure
end
```

Basically you can update all values for a graphics handle, in this case 'p' and 's'. If you open the matlab doc for [`plot`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) or [`plot3`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) you will find a link to all properties of that primitive: e.g. [Line Properties](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html). Similar documentation pages exist for `scatter`/`imagesc` etc.

So the general idea is to first create a figure with the first frame, save the handles to the objects you would like to update (`p = plot(...`), and then enter a loop in which you update the required property of that graphics object (e.g. `p.Color = 'r'`, or `p.XData = ...`).

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is quite similar to what I already have. I would have preferred to just create the raw graphics objects without the figure, instead of having to do both at the same time, but maybe that is just not how matlab does things. I feel like these kinds of solutions, apart from being a bit hacky, make it hard to do more advanced treatment of the objects, like combining multiple animating figures in a single window, for example.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that it I'm better served wrapping everything in a "PlottingUI" class. After reading up a bit I can now control the hierarchy of `uifigure`, `uigridlayout`, `uiaxes`, etc., pretty well, and I can have an update loop in the main class that updates the plot in a synced way. It is actually turning out pretty well.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your answer even though I went a different way, to thank you for your effort and so that the question will be closed.